# Bitcoin QT wallet.dat file location?

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, bitcoin-qt-setup

It's been since 2013 when i was mining bitcoin that i have used and synchronized this wallet. I've tried a few times several years ago but it literally takes days, if not weeks now to synchronize, AND, before it finishes it always conks out and gives some error and starts over. It's on my old MacBook air.
How do i get the remaining bitcoin out and put into a new wallet somewhere else where it's accessible?? If anyone can help me get access to this wallet i will send a $100 in bitcoin :)
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks
Derek

Comment: Started digging around into the files of the BitcoinQT wallet app and found a file called CodeResources... in this file I have found keys!! However, there are literally 20 different keys. 
The line reads like this: <key>Resources/qt.sv.qm</key><data>then the actual key. The location(?) in-between the "<key>" is different for each one. next one might be <key>Resources/qt_he.qm</key>.... 
how can i try to deposit each one of these keys into some other wallet like Coinbase? I was about to try but couldn't find a place to manually enter a key. the "Resources/bitcoin.icns" one seems positive

Comment: .... but the one directly beneath that one is <key>Resources/empty.lproj</key>... not as positive.

Comment: Are you using windows? First of all you should check which version of Bitcoin core wallet you are using, if you are using an old version it will not be supported anymore by the network. Go to the website and download the latest wallet version and give it a try, also make sure to have a backup of the wallet.dat + your password.